# Android Studio 2.1.3 - .so file not updating

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, native

I have an Android Studio projet that depends on an external .so file compiled with another IDE. Whenever my .so is linked, I copy and paste it into the `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` folder of my Android project, erasing the existing one, if any.

However, most of the time, it seems like Android Studio is not taking that change into account and keeps reusing the old version of the .so file. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, and I have not figured out what exactly is causing it to or not to work.

How can I do for the .so file to be updated ? I saw an SO answer providing a piece of gradle script to manually copy the .so file, but it doesn't fit my particular case since I have multiple .so files, one debug and one release for each CPU.